# jQuery - better way to concatenate strings that have quotations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Is there a better way to concatenate strings that have "'s (such as HTML tag attribute definitions) in jQuery than escaping the quote?

Escapy Example:

`$(this).prepend("<label for=\""+$(this).attr("id")+"\">"+"a"+"</label>");`

Comment: Use single quotes for HTML tag attribute definitions?

Comment: hum i was wondering if jQuery might possibly have a function to process such strings

Comment: For the record: `$(this).attr("id")` is a bloated and redundant way of saying `this.id`.

Comment: i'm still not sure when to use `this` vs `$(this)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the object method of creation ([`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)), like this:

```
$('<label />', { for: this.id, text: 'a' }).prependTo(this);
//or:
$(this).prepend($('<label />', { for: this.id, text: 'a' }));
```

This has the advantage of calling [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) internally, taking care of any encoding issues.  Also, if you're doing this a *lot*, it'll be faster, since the HTML fragment is consistent and cached, so a clone of the node is used, rather than turning a string into a document fragment each time.  The more elements like this you're creating, the faster it is over the string method.  For the same caching reasons, the bigger the element (up to a 512 char string) the bigger the gains.

Answer (score 6):

you can use single quotes for the main string and then you don't have to escape the double quote.

```
$(this).prepend('<label for="'+$(this).attr("id")+'">'+ a +'</label>');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is why I primarily use single quotes `$('here')`. Less to worry about when you're working with HTML that inevitably is full of double quotes.

```
$('""""No worries!"""""""')
```

The [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Strings#Strings) agrees.

Comment: what if you have html with words like `"Ben Franklin's kite"`?

Comment: Well, then you're back to escaping. Nothing's perfect, right? May as well code to make the most common case easier.

Comment: or what when you need to echo it with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes?

```
$(this).prepend('<label for="'+$(this).attr("id")+'">'+'a'+'</label>');
```

or, jQuery:

```
$("<label>").attr("for", this.id).text(a).prependTo(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are definitely the way to go.  I recommend using them for all strings in javascript.  Particularly when working with jQuery, it is much more common to need to use a double quote inside a string than a single quote, so it will save you a lot of time escaping and improve readability.  Additionally, it'll save you keystrokes, no more pesky shift key :)